# How to send email with smtplib module through the proxy?

Tags: python, proxy, smtp, smtplib

I've a problem with the python's module smtplib: at work, the pc is connected by a proxy. When I run the code:

```python
server = smtplib.SMTP()
server.connect('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.login('username','password')
server.sendmail('from', 'to', 'msg')
server.quit()
```

this error message appears:

> File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 386, in create_connection
>       for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
>       socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

I think it's caused by the proxy, that blocks the connection.
The pc is enabled to surf in internet.
How can I send an email through the proxy?
ps:(I'm italian, sorry for my "italish")

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your DNS resolution does not work. That's what the error tells you.

Answer (score 0):

the following will work:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com',port=465)
server.login('username@gmail.com','password')
server.sendmail('from', 'to', 'msg')
```